# Favicon Icon Not Working

Tags: html, css, favicon

I am Trying to add a favicon into my website. I created the icon on https://www.favicon-generator.org/ and pasted in the given code. I'm sure the file directory is right as I've checked multiple times. Could someone help me out, what styling to I need to add or remove or am I missing something?

```
  <DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Drafted</title>
<head>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="bg">

<video id="video-bg" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Video Not Supported :(
    </video>

</div>

<div class="form">
<a href="#" target="_blank">
SUBMIT A BACKGROUND VIDEO!
</a>
</div>


<div class="text">
<a href="#" target="_blank">
drafted
</a>
</div>

<div class="steam">
<a href="#" target="_blank">
STEAM
</a>
</div>

<div class="esea">
<a href="#" target="_blank">
ESEA
</a>
</div>

<div class="twitter">
<a href="#" target="_blank">
TWITTER
</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Favicons have a tendency to cache super-aggressively.

Your code doesn't appear to be off, but I would suggest the following troubleshooting steps:

- Try accessing the same page in a different browser. Make sure that going to `/favicon.ico` directly in the browser actually works, and gives you the icon you expect.
- Load the page in a different browser (or a different computer) - one that has preferably never seen this page before.

I'm not sure it's related to this, but there a couple of issues with other parts of the code that could possibly be causing this side-effect;

- You've missed a `!` in your doctype - it should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- Your `title` should be inside your `head` section.

I suggest also running your html through a [linter](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html), as badly formed html can have really strange side effects sometimes.

Comment: I'm not sure, but Chrome actually tries to get `favicon` even if it's not there in markup, each time.

Comment: Thanks, turns out it was my file directory It was hidden In a folder I didn't see. Thanks for telling me about linter too never heard of it before!

Answer (score 0):

Your favicon is referenced correctly in your HTML, and should display. As such, there are only a few possible causes of your problem. Check whether you can navigate to `www.yourwebsite.com/favicon.ico` manually.

If so, there's a caching issue:

1. Try clearing your HTML cache. This can be done by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.
2. Try clearing your CSS cache. This can be done by holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while clicking on the refresh icon of your browser.
3. Try a hard refresh. This is done by holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>R</kbd>.

If not, the problem is that the file isn't found:

1. You may not have got your favicon stored at the root of your project. Ensure that the file is actually at root level.
2. You may not have uploaded your favicon to the server. Check whether the file exists on the server itself.
3. If the file exists on the server, ensure that it is a valid .ico image.

You also have invalid markup, which may be the cause of your issue:

1. Your `<DOCTYPE>` tag needs an exclamation mark before `html`.
2. Your `<title>` tag should be inside `<head>`.

I would recommend running your HTML through a markup validation service, such as [**The W3C Markup Validation Service**](https://validator.w3.org), to ensure that you have valid HTML.

Confirming all of that and fixing up those two errors should almost certainly fix your favicon not coming through.

Hope this helps!